# onmouseover onmousemove executing so many times

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var zoomPad = document.getElementsByClassName('zoomPad');
zoomPad[0].onmouseover = function(){
    var action = 'image_zoom';
    // Check if the activity is already logged
    var checkCookie = getCookie('image_zoom');
    if(checkCookie != '')
        return false;

    //Log activity of hovering image
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url:  '/ajaxCall/user-activity-ajax.php',
        data: {action:action},
        success: function(response)
        {
            document.cookie = "image_zoom  = " + action;
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
} // end zoomPad
```

Hi,
I am trying to log a user event when he mouse over the image..but it should not be logged more than once on a signle page that's why i implemented cookie to stop executing ajax more than once.

But as soon i load the page and move my mouse over thei mage some times 5 , some time 9 calls are being fired to ajax . Same mechanism i applied to another drop down in a page but thats working fine.

THanks

Comment: Depending on what browsers you need to support I would consider using LocalStorage rather thank cookies

Comment: i want it on every browser ofcourse

Comment: `onmouseenter` would only fire when, well, the pointer enters the element, not as long as it moves over the element.

Comment: @pawel onmouseenter is IE-specific. Doesn't work in other browsers unless you use jQuery which can simulate this event

Comment: @RubenSerrate According to MDN it does work in Chrome 30+, Firefox, IE5.5+ and Opera 17+, Safari support is unknown: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseenter

Comment: @pawel Sorry my bad, it used to be IE-specific. Unknown support for Safari would reason enough not to use it though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okey,

One solution to this problem is to use jQuery more effectively by using "one" method to bind certain function to be run only once per element. This way, you can be certain that it won't re-run until it is necessary.

```
/*
Bind trackZoomPadActivity method to a mouseover, but do it using "one",
so it is binded to call mouseover only once
*/
$('.zoomPad').one("mouseover", trackZoomPadActivity);
```

The point when it should be re-run is when you detect through your ajax request that tracking has failed because of some unknown error with your server.

```
request.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
    // if request fails, we re-bind trackZoomPadActivity method, so
    // person can try to mouseover again
    $that.one("mouseover", trackZoomPadActivity);
});
```

Other than these points, here is a full code below which should work. The idea is to track event once per element & only re-attempt to redo the action if request has failed with the server:

**Full code in JavaScript:**

```
/*
Bind trackZoomPadActivity method to a mouseover, but do it using "one",
so it is binded to call mouseover only once
*/
$('.zoomPad').one("mouseover", trackZoomPadActivity);

/**
 * Method for tracking zoomPad activity
 *
 */
function trackZoomPadActivity() {

    // action for this zoomPad
    var action = 'image_zoom',
        // referencing to self
        $that = $(this);

    // check if the activity is already logged
    var checkCookie = readCookie(action);

    // if cookie exists already -- return
    if(checkCookie) {
        return false;
    }

    // log activity of hovering image
    var request = $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url:  '/ajaxCall/user-activity-ajax.php',
        data: { action: action }
    });

    request.done(function(msg) {
        // request is processed successfully, we can save the cookie!
        document.cookie = 'image_zoom = ' + action;
    });

    request.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
        // if request fails, we re-bind trackZoomPadActivity method, so
        // person can try to mouseover again
        $that.one("mouseover", trackZoomPadActivity);
    });

}

/**
 * Method for reading cookie value
 *
 */
function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}
```

**Example of HTML elements for testing:**

```
<img src="http://placehold.it/64/64" class="zoomPad" />
<img src="http://placehold.it/64/64" class="zoomPad" />
```

Cheers.

Comment: V thank you so much this is helpful for now to complete the task :) but i'll b very thankful to you if you provide the solution in javascript. Think of me as a starter of javascript. thanks

Comment: @user3445065 all the code I posted is javascript :) so, np!

Answer (score 2):

Works well here : http://jsfiddle.net/7g5LX/

Maybe you should try this getCookie function (from http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp) :

```
function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) != -1) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
    }
    return "";
}
```

Or call your cookie setter outside the ajax behavior (your set your cookie when your ajax call return 'success')

Comment: I doubt that this solves the problem entirely, another events can fire as long as the request is pending(?) - therefore there will be more than 1 request. You need to check pending cases. Also, I think normal cookies are pretty much done for, at least for this kind of stuff. (imo), localStorage as @RuvenSerrate mentioned could be better and pretty widely supported http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html

Comment: localStorage is a good choice, unless it must support IE7. I think @ser3445065 should register his cookie before the ajax call to avoid multiple ajax request if some are pending. It's the easiest way imo.

Comment: @user2317387 so i did it before ajax ? isn't it ? i am not getting your point

Comment: @user2317387 for your point i guess you are saying that as the ajax success is pending my event continues to fire ? ..I used async: false for that .. this isn't helping yet ;

Comment: Currently, you set your cookie in the "Success" part. You should try to set it before your ajax call. Async:false should never be used.

Comment: @user2317387 sir its part of my logic to set the cookie when i received success from ajax.. changing this will disturb my code.